# Truncat log message in powershell

Tags: powershell, events

I try to truncat the first line of wifi log with Powershell and I do not why it is not working. Could anyone suggest what is wrong with following code?

```
(Get-WinEvent -Logname Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig/Operational | select -first 1).Message.split('`n')[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(Get-WinEvent -Logname Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig/Operational | select -first 1).Message.split("`n")[0]
```

Single quoted strings are treated as literals, I think you were splitting on the letter 'n' :)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 1):

I think you are better off using the regex `-split` to split the message on newline characters:

```
((Get-WinEvent -Logname Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig/Operational | Select-Object -First 1).Message -split '\r?\n')[0]
```

> ```
> \r       Match a carriage return character
>    ?     Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> \n       Match a line feed character
> ```